# Hiding form after login

Tags: php, session

I've hit a road block in my PHP development where I am printing a form based on the existence of session variables. If there is a session variable called username, i don't want to print the login form, however this code only works when the page is refreshed.

Is there any way to overcome this issue using only PHP so that the form is hidden as soon as the user logs in rather than having to refresh.

Relevant code:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    print "Hello, " . $_SESSION['username'];

  } else {

    echo '<form method="post" action="' ?> <?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>

    <?php 

      echo '">

      Username: <input type="text" name="username" class="username" />
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" class="password" />
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="submit_btn" />

      </form>';

}

?>

...

<?php

  ...

  if ($final_hash == $db_pass) {

$_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;  
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

  } else {

print "wrong pass!";

  }
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Sidenote: If you're yet not loading `session_start();` anywhere; do. Otherwise, your echo'ed session won't echo.

Comment: Why not use two separate pages and check for a session and redirect them based off that?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah I am Fred, thanks though.

Comment: You're welcome; just checking. It's not in your code. (Had to ask) ;-)

Comment: @Chitowns24 This page isn't specifically a login page, the login form will be on every signle page on the site allowing the users to log in from anywhere so I'm not sure that would work?

Comment: You may need to use jQuery or Javascript then to hide it. Because you can't hide something on a page without refreshing using PHP

Comment: Try this logic instead: `if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])) { // do something } else{ // do something else }` @Charlieabee

Answer (score 1):

You could submit the form with Ajax, set the session variables, then use java script to hide the form. You can't do it just with PHP because PHP is a server side language.  Unless you send the client to the server (reload the page in some way) you can't hide it with out a client-side language.